# Migrating to GCM breaks the build process

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm trying to migrate my app and adding classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' breaks the build:

This is my top level gradle.build:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.hamsterksu:android-appversion-gradle-plugin:1.2.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Doing that fails the build with the following message:

[image: Android Studio error message]

> What went wrong:
>   A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:zipalignAppDebug'.
>
> File
>   '/path../outputs/apk/app-app-debug-unaligned.apk' specified for property 'inputFile' does not exist.

Comment: Make sure you have the lastest Android gradle plugin, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3` and run a `gradlew clean`.

Comment: same problem with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3` or `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1`

Comment: I think you are using the wrong plugin. Remove that services plugin and add this dependency: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0`. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

Comment: I have play-services-gcm in my project build.gradle. The above is the top level gradle file. The google-services plugin is suppose to read in the `google-services.json` and create string values with the default names. It's a 'convenience' thing that they added as a mandatory step: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

If I could find which are the default names I needed to use I'd drop that from my build and just hardcoded the values. This is getting ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

i have found these problem too, and i found its because i have using 22 buildtoolsversion

change your buildToolsVersion to version 23, and it will work again

open app/build.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "packagename.id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode appVersionCode
    versionName appVersionName
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
  }
}
```